# Redis Connection Timeout

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I am using spring boot to connect to redis (docker) if i am running redis on default port I can access from my application, but if I used different port (6382) i am getting timeout although I have the following properties

spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6382

and

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.test")

public class RedisConfig {



    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you confirmed redis service running on port, can you connect from another terminal with redis-cli ?

Comment: yes it is running on the correct port

Comment: I was running using
docker run -d -p 6385:6379 

but then I changed to docker run -d -p 6385:6385 and it worked

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: If you recently moved from Spring Boot `2.x` to `3.x` for instance, the Spring Data (Redis) properties changed from `spring.redis.*` to `spring.data.redis.*`.